# Есть ли утилита для построение миграции (Laravel) по существующей БД?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Ну и если не найду - будет ли такая утилита востребована?

Comment: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Comment: хз кто так делает, с миграций начинают, а если миграций нет, то что это за проект вообще))

Comment: ==что это за проект вообще== Микросервисная архитектура

Comment: ==github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator== - не захотел устанавливаться. Ладно, придётся написать утилитку.